# What is the meaning of "tie their shoes"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the crime/drama movie *Drugstore Cowboy*, after returning to his hometown, Bob talks to a drug counselor lady:

> Lady: Have you ever considered becoming a counselor and helping other
>   addicts with their problems?
>
> Bob: No.
>
> Lady: Why not?
>
> Bob: Well, to begin with, nobody and I mean nobody can talk a
>   junkie out of using. You can talk to them for years, but sooner or
>   later they'll get a hold of something. Maybe it's not dope.  Maybe it's
>   booze.  Maybe it's glue. Maybe it's gasoline. Maybe it's a gunshot in
>   the head. But something. Something to relieve the pressures of their
>   everyday life, like... having to **tie their shoes**.

Comment: *Tying your shoes* means tightening the laces and tying knots in them shoelaces so the shoes don't fall off your feet. It's given as an instance of the pressures of everyday life.

Comment: *Like tying your shoes* or comparison with tying your shoes is often something like an idiom to mean a trivial activity that any normal person can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, "tie their shoes" means exactly what it says.  You tie your shoes -- which is to say, you pull the laces tight and knot them -- to keep your shoes from falling off.

This is called ["tongue-in-cheek" humor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek). The statement does not literally mean that a junkie will find it difficult to tie their shoes.  Rather it mentions a completely ordinary activity to reinforce the earlier comment that a junkie will inevitably start using drugs again -- that they will use any excuse, no matter how trivial, to justify their habit.