# How to know myself whether it is Idiom or not?

Tags: idioms

I posted a question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139231/what-is-the-meaning-of-tie-their-shoes), Which is **Idiom**, but google showed nothing about it.

So how to know myself whether it is Idiom or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually spot an idiom because it does not literally make sense in the context that it's being used.

- *I'm not going outside because **it's raining cats and dogs***.

"pressures of everyday life... **like having to tie his shoes**," doesn't really make sense when talking about the difficulties that might cause you to use drugs because it's way too trivial. It's being used to represent a simple task.  This idiom is usually seen like this -- "he can't even tie his own shoes." (he's incompetent)

You can't really memorize all of the idioms in a language because they can be created any time and used as long as they make sense to the people who are listening. "In-jokes" are a type of idiom too. You start to pick them up as you become familiar with the culture that's using the language.  There are different English idioms in different English speaking countries - although there is some overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to learn idioms is to memorize them one at a time. If you google "dictionary of english idioms" you will find a number of books on the subject, which list thousands of them. If you google "english idioms" you will find any number of links with lists of them, such as [this one](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/vocabulary-lesson-idioms-alphabetical-order.php).