# Should it be "the number of" or "the numbers of" when assigning n numbers to n groups?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

I have 3 groups with 3 different number(s) of subjects in each one. Should I say

> The *number*/*numbers* of subjects in groups 1, 2, and 3 *is*/*are* x, y, and z, respectively.

I presume that since I have 3 groups, the subject should be *numbers*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know myself whether it is Idiom or not?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/how-to-know-myself-whether-it-is-idiom-or-not)

Comment: @DaniilManokhin What’s the connection between that question and this one?

Answer (score 1):

*The number of* is correct.

*The number of* is used for plural nouns and therefore is correct.

Comment: I know that "the number of" is followed by plural nouns and takes a "singular" verb, but my question is a situation that there is more than one number. By the way, I wonder what the question you have marked as the possible duplicate of mine has anything to do with mine!